# Some basics about Bracket Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, complex-numbers, poisson-brackets

I'm trying to prove something. Sorry this post is so long but I wanted to keep things as basic as possible so people have an easier time understanding.

Let's assume we have a quantum system $\rho$ which evolves unitarily. During the process the Hamiltonian $H$ is getting externally varied, so that the evolution of $\rho$ is described by an unitary U.

Now what we do is to make a measurement of $\rho$ at the beginning. Let's say we obtain some state $\left|n\right>$ with probability $P_n$, with $P_n = \left<n|\rho|n\right> = \rho_{nn}$.

Now the process of the Unitary is implemented and our state $\left|n\right>$ evolves accordingly to U. After some time we make a second measurement and obtain $\left|m^f\right>$ where the f denotes that it is the final state.

Now we are interested in the conditional probability to find this $\left|m^f\right>$ under the condition we found state $\left|n\right>$ before. This conditional probability can be expressed as: $P_{n,m} =|\left<m^f|U|n\right>|^2$.

Additionally we have another unitary $V$ which transforms the hamiltonian basis $\left|m^f\right> = V \left|i\right>$ such that we can rewrite $P_{n,m} =|\left<m|V^{\dagger}U|n\right>|^2$.

My first question: Is there any smart way I could rewrite $P_{n,m}$ ? I'm not very good with the dirac notation and all I was able to achieve is rewrite the square:

$P_{n,m} =|\left<n|U^{\dagger}V|m\right>\left<m|V^{\dagger}U|n\right>|$

That's all.

I would need to that because ultimately what we have been doing is measuring two energy values. We are intersted in getting these states $\left|n\right>$ and $\left|m\right>$ because eventually we could substract them to obtain the work $W_{(nm)} = E_n - E_m$.

So putting all pieces together we define the Work:

$W = \sum_{nm} p_{(nm)}W_{(nm)}$

where $p_{(nm)}$ is the total probability of first getting state n and later obtainin m so:

$p_{(nm)} =\rho_{nn}P_{n,m} $

and somehow I need to take this $W = \sum_{nm} p_{(nm)}W_{(nm)}$ and rewrite it in several ways to achieve things like:

$W = \sum_{nm} p_{(nm)}W_{(nm)} = \sum_n \rho_{nn}E_n - \sum_{nm} \rho_{nn}P_{n,m}E^f_m$

which ok....I have no idea how to derive this (which I would like to in bracket notation) but I can kinda agree because it basically says "Prob. of initial state times initial energy - Prob. of final state times final energy"

But can anyone help me to understand how to obtain this result via bracket notation or at all ?

And then they go further and say:

$W = \sum_n \rho_{nn}E_n - \sum_{nm} \rho_{nn}P_{n,m}E^f_m $

$ = \sum_n \rho_{nn}E_n - \sum_{nm} \rho_{nn}E^f_m U_{kn}U^*_{ln}V_{lm}V^*_{km}$

where * is supposed to be the complex conjuagte of the unitary operators. I have no idea where k and l come from though. Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use "\langle" and "\rangle" instead of "<" and ">" for your brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your set of states $|n\rangle$ is complete, you can always insert an identity in betwee two operators, a bra and a ket, or an operator and a bra-ket:

$$\mathbb I=\sum_n |n\rangle\langle n|$$

In this way you can make appear the matrix elements of U and V in the decomposition you wrote:

$$\langle m|U V^\dagger|k\rangle= \langle m|U\sum_n  |n\rangle\langle n| V^\dagger|k\rangle=\sum_n \langle m|U  |n\rangle\langle n| V^\dagger|k\rangle\equiv \sum_n U_{mn} (V^\dagger)_{nk}$$

And we know that

$$(V^\dagger)_{nk}=V_{kn}^*$$

Comment: Thanks with this I was able to solve the first part! It's obvious things like these that I just haven't learned properly yet.

Comment: You’re welcome bro, I didn’t go further because I don’t want to steal you all the fun, but if you need more development tell me

Comment: Next comment, made some error

Comment: 1. Well I was able to solve it and obtained in the end what I wanted! Again thank you. Now I'm kinda trying to understand the result. 

Reminder:

I now got the results for work:
1.$\sum_i \rho_{ii} E_i - \sum  \rho_{ii} E^f_j U_{ki}U^*_{li}V_{lj}V^*_{kj} $
2. $\sum_i \rho_{ii} E_i -  \rho_{im} E^f_j U_{ki}U^*_{lm}V_{lj}V^*_{kj} $

where we can see that they are identical if m=i, or in other words when $\rho$ has only diagonal elements.

Comment: 2.Now this is something interesting I was hoping you could tell me a bit about.
$\rho$ being diagonal means that it is a classical physical system that has NO coherence. 

Now I was trying to understand the meaning of this which I'm still not so sure about. To confirm I tried to make the same calculation (as in initial energy - final energy = work) for a $\rho$ that HAS off-diagonal terms (thus should have coherence).

Comment: 3.So I calc. W = $Tr(\rho H)$ - $Tr(\rho^f H)$ but either I'm doing sth. terribly wrong or the off-diagonal terms had no effect whatsoever on the systems energy. 

Supposedly this whole thought-experiment should convince me that our def. of work W only makes sense for classical, diagonal $\rho$, but all it has done was to confuse me. 

Bonus info that might be helpful: It is implied that after the first measurement is done all coherence present in the system is destroyed. But a system with no coherence remains the same. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry bro I can't be of much help with interpretation of these results